# Arrays: Find Numbers with Even Number of Digits

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Nodigeven {
    static int even=0;
    static int count=0;
    static int findnodigeven(int[] arr) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            while(arr[i]!=0) {
                arr[i]= arr[i]/10;
                count++;
            }
            if(count%2==0) {
                even++;
            }
        }
return even;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {122,255,133,14,15,16};
        System.out.println(findnodigeven(arr));
    }   
}
```

---

am getting wrong output i.e : 1 .. can you tell me where i am going wrong here  in the code

Comment: You never reset `count` whenever you're testing another number from your array. So `count` will be `3, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15` respectively, which gives you `1` even number as a result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell you have two errors.  The first is that you did not reset `count to 0` for each iteration of the loop.  The second is that you did not check the special case of `0` in the array. `0` is a single digit and thus odd.  But since you never enter the while loop, count will remain `0` and even will be incremented.

```
public class Nodigeven {
    
    
    static int findnodigeven(int[] arr) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;

            // check for 0 value and skip.
            if (arr[i] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            while (arr[i] != 0) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] / 10;
                count++;
            }
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                even++;
            }
        }
        return even;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 122, 255,0, 133, 14, 15, 16 };
        System.out.println(findnodigeven(arr));
    }
}
```

If you're interested you and do this without explicitly counting the digits. Use `Math.log10()` to get the count, again skipping `0` since the `log of 0` is undefined. The number of digits in a decimal number N is `Math.log10(N)+1`. You can use the `conditional operator` to add `1` or `0` as appropriate to the parity count.

```
public class Nodigeven {
    static int even = 0;
    
    static int findnodigeven(int[] arr) {
        int even = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            even += arr[i] != 0 &&
                (int) (Math.log10(arr[i])+1) % 2 == 0 
                          ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return even;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 122, 255,0, 133, 14, 15, 16 };
        System.out.println(findnodigeven(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution am looking for . thanks WJS